# Why is the kinematic viscosity unit m²/s when you only measure the time it passes a certain distance through a capillary rheometer?

Tags: viscosity

Why did the scientists who designed the kin.viscosity measurement using a capillary rheometer setup decide to express the results in m<sup>2</sup>/s when all you measure is the time: the less viscous (faster flowing) a fluid is, the faster it will cover the fixed distance in a capillary rheometer.
Kin. viscosity = the time for the distance covered in seconds (or minutes) x the rheometer constant = less m<sup>2</sup>/s for a faster flowing fluid. So the unit doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Units can be funny. If you multiply out the units in L/100km for fuel consumption you get volume / distance = area! (You'll get the same result in miles/gallon after some conversions.) The area would represent the cross-section of a tube of fuel that you would consume as you drove along the journey.

Comment: L/100km is weird. As you slow down and approach 0 km/h the consumption shoots up to infinity. Very non-intuitive but it makes sense, as it will take you forever to reach 100 km.

Answer (score 0):

Because the kinematic viscosity unit is the division of dynamic viscosity $ μ =\text{ absolute or dynamic viscosity (N s/m^2)}$ by the $density$.

$$ν = \frac{ μ}{  ρ}$$

- $μ = \text{absolute or dynamic viscosity (N s/m^2)}$
- $ρ = density \ (kg/m3)$
- $ν = kinematic\ viscosity\ (m^2/s)$

The m^2 in the dynamic viscosity comes from Newton's definition of tangential force per unit area required to move one horizontal plane with respect to another plane - at a unit velocity - when maintaining a unit distance apart in the fluid. It is the area of the layer being considered. [see here.](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/dynamic-absolute-kinematic-viscosity-d_412.html)

## Edit

To obtain kinematic viscosity (v = ny), we multiply the capillary measured flow time (tf) by the so-called capillary constant (KC). This constant needs to be determined for each capillary by calibrating the capillary, i.e. by measuring a reference liquid of known viscosity. [source][2]

$$v = K _{C} {\cdot} t _{f} $$

[2]: https://wiki.anton-paar.com/us-en/how-to-measure-viscosity/#:~:text=To%20obtain%20kinematic%20viscosity%20(v,reference%20liquid%20of%20known%20viscosity.

Comment: I know the relationship between the two viscosity types but the capillary viscometer test measures kinematic viscosity directly. Your answer does not explain how they get to a m^2/s value just based on measuring the time passing between two measurement points multiplied by a viscometer constant.

Comment: @AdrianG. i edited my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks! I also found a clear explanation here: https://mycoscience.com/how-to-calculate-parenteral-product-viscosity-using-the-capillary-viscometer-method/#:~:text=The%20capillary%20method%20is%20used,capillary%20viscometers%20(Method%202).